How to conditionally display the table of contents in one or multiple columns in Beamer?
I am trying to create a Beamer presentation where the TOC is displayed in one or more columns based on the number of elements in the TOC. If the number of elements is equal to, say, 20, the TOC should be displayed in 3 columns; otherwise, it should be in one column.
I have referred to the following questions but couldn't find a solution that fits my needs:

Grouped two column table of contents in Beamer
Splitting TOC into two columns on single frame in beamer
Two-column beamer ToC with control over the breaking point

I am looking for a solution based on the number of elements in the TOC. For example, if the number of elements is 20, I want to be able to split the TOC into 3 columns using multicol.
Here is my minimal (non) working example (MWE) because of \value{nb_elements_in_toc} which I don't know how to get:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol} % For multiple columns
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For conditions

\definecolor{escp}{RGB}{36, 0, 133}

\newcommand{\tocframe}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\textcolor{escp}{Table of Contents}}
        \ifnum\value{nb_elements_in_toc}>20 % Adjust this number as needed
            \begin{multicols}{3}
                \tableofcontents
            \end{multicols}
        \else
            \tableofcontents
        \fi
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

% Title page
\begin{frame}
    \title{Presentation Title}
    \author{Author Name}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\tocframe


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    Content of the introduction.
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Methodology}
    Content of the methodology.
\end{frame}

\section{Results}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Results}
    Content of the results.
\end{frame}

\section{Discussion}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Discussion}
    Content of the discussion.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Conclusion}
    Content of the conclusion.
\end{frame}

\section{Appendices}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Appendices}
    Content of the appendices.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Beamer stores the number of sections in \beamer@sectionmax:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocframe}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \ifnum\the\beamer@sectionmax>6
            {\begin{multicols}{3}
                \tableofcontents
            \end{multicols}}
        \else
            \tableofcontents
        \fi
    \end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}

% Title page
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\tocframe


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    Content of the introduction.
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Methodology}
    Content of the methodology.
\end{frame}

\section{Results}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Results}
    Content of the results.
\end{frame}

\section{Discussion}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Discussion}
    Content of the discussion.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Conclusion}
    Content of the conclusion.
\end{frame}

\section{Appendices}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Appendices}
    Content of the appendices.
\end{frame}

\section{Appendices}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Appendices}
    Content of the appendices.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


thank you Ms Beamer :)

@JeT You're welcome!
